# Use map.on Click for different events (edit Drawing, Popup) on Openlayers map

Tags: openlayers

I want to use the GpPluginOl3.js plugin (from the french geoportail [see on gitHub](https://github.com/IGNF/geoportal-extensions/blob/master/README-ol3.md#drawing) (description in french)) together with popups, but I cannot use them together.

The drawing tools allow me to draw points, lines, polygons and even to edit them, but I cannot change the style, edit text or delete features. When I'm removing the popups, everything works fine.
It seems as if my code is interacting in a strange way with the code of the drawing tools.
I've observed the following three cases:

1. clicking on feature => shows popup with correct values of my placeholders
2. clicking on new drawn polygon => nothing happens when trying to change style, edit text or delete this polygon
3. clicking on a new drawn polygon, that overlaps with an existing feature => popup shows up, but placeholders don't get replaced with values AND the popup for styling, editing shows up and new drawn polygons can even be deleted.

Here the code I use for my popups:

```
    var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
    map.addOverlay(popup);
```

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var popupContent = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(layer) {     
            return layer.get('content'); // template-string of layer
        });

    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function(feature, layer) {
            return feature; // get feature at pixel on layer 
        });

    if (feature) {
        popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        var atts = feature.getProperties(); // object
        for (var prop in atts) {
            var re = new RegExp("{" + prop + "}", "g");
            popupContent = popupContent.replace(re, atts[prop]); // replace {placeholder} with values of feature
        }
        popup.show(evt.coordinate,popupContent);
    }        
    else {
        popup.hide();
    }
});
```

In the console I get the following security error:

SecurityError: The operation is insecure. ol-debug.js:69965
ol.renderer.canvas.IntermediateCanvas.prototype.forEachLayerAtCoordinate https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:69965:21
ol.renderer.canvas.Map.prototype.forEachLayerAtPixel https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:23693:16
ol.Map.prototype.forEachLayerAtPixel https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:32543:10
init/< https://example.com/js/map.js:797:28
boundListener https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:7208:12
ol.events.EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:7628:11
ol.Map.prototype.handleMapBrowserEvent https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:32860:7
boundListener https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:7208:12
ol.events.EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:7628:11
ol.MapBrowserEventHandler.prototype.emulateClick_ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:12866:3
ol.MapBrowserEventHandler.prototype.handlePointerUp_ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:12920:5
boundListener https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:7208:12
ol.events.EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:7628:11
ol.pointer.PointerEventHandler.prototype.fireEvent https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:12668:3
ol.pointer.PointerEventHandler.prototype.up https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:12546:3
ol.pointer.MouseSource.prototype.mouseup https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:11192:7
<anonym> self-hosted:943:17
ol.pointer.PointerEventHandler.prototype.eventHandler_ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:12468:5
boundListener https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.3.2/ol-debug.js:7208:12

Maybe someone has an idea where the problem could lie? or where i should impove my code.